# jQuery Validation Highlighting One Label for Two Fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, validation, jquery-validate

I have a form validation script using the jQuery Validation plugin where for the phone area, there are 2 fields, area code and phone number. However, there is only one label for both fields that reads "Phone." Both fields are required in the validation.

So when there is an error in the phone field, the label gets highlighted and the error message is shown. If there is an error in the area code field, the error message is shown but the label doesn't get the error class so it doesn't get the highlight.

Can anyone think of a way to highlight the "Phone" label and display the correct message when the area code field does not validate? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom rule for the phone field that checks the area code field as well. Like

`jQuery.validator.addMethod('PHONE',function() {
        *check both inputs, return true if both correct*
})`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem where I want to show an error class for one label (Expiration Date) whether Expiration Month or Expiration Year was empty. As Steerpike mentions, you're not allowed to say something like `<label for="expirationDate,expirationYear">`, so I'm just picking one and changing the other in a custom `showErrors` function:

HTML:

```
<label for="expirationMonth">Expiration Date:</label>
<input type="text" name="expirationMonth"> / <input type="text" name='expirationYear'>
```

JS:

```
$("#form").validate({
  .
  .                                           //error messages, rules, etc. go here
  .
  showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
    this.defaultShowErrors();                 //default show errors behavior
    $.each(errorMap, function(key, value) {
      if(key == 'expirationYear') {           //if key is the input without label,
        key = 'expirationMonth';              //make it the label's "for" input
      } 
      $('#form').find('label[for=' + key + ']').addClass('alert');  //add label class
    });
  }
});
```

If you have any other situations like this, you would just add another if statement / else if statement.

Answer (score -2):

Associating a label with two elements is actually invalid html and not recommended.

From the [w3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.9):

> Each LABEL element is associated with exactly one form control.

I would suggest adding a second label element for postcode and removing it visually from the screen if you don't want it to be seen by the user by setting its margin to -999em or a similar method.

Comment: I understand that. This would be adding an error class to a different label via the jquery validation plugin. It has nothing to do with standards.